# How to control excel cells together with vba script?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

In the userform there are product names (**combobox**) , prices , amount (**textbox**). For product name control I use with combobox . I write amount of product to my textbox as a manuel  when I choose the product name , I want to do that next cell will write cost of this product's price after that When I write amount of this product to amount cell , Excel will calculate the total price and show me total price at total price cell. I get prices from my specific excel sheet and i creat a formula for that . When I change product name in worksheet( **prdocut name cell fixed as a list**) everything is ok but when I use the script and when I choose product name from Combobox and write to worksheet via userform prices cell don't changes when product name changes and don't calculate total prices.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

   With cboProduct
    .AddItem "Iron"
    .AddItem "Plank"
    .AddItem "ANOTHER PRODUCT1"
    .AddItem "ANOTHER PRODUCT2"
    .AddItem "ANOTHER PRODUCT3"
    .AddItem "ANOTHER PRODUCT4"

End With
End Sub

     Private Sub cboProduct_Change()

     End Sub

     Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("list").Activate
         Range("A33").Select
     Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 3).Select
End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True


 Range("C20").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = txtAmount.Value

 Range("A20").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = cboProductName.Value

txtAmount.Value = ""
cboProduct.Value = ""
Range("A33").Select
 End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your problem description, it sounds like things work the way you want when you click "ok" in the user form, but not when you change a product from the user form control. This is because your event function "Sub cboProduct_Change()" is empty. If you want the event of changing it have the same effect as "ok", you can either call cmdOK_click() or create a third more generic update function that both change and ok events call.

You don't mention how column D gets populated. It seems that the spreadsheet has formulas pre-populated there. It might be more reliable to re-add the column D formula during this OK event.

Also, you can streamline some code without moving the active cell. For example, instead of:

```
Range("C20").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = txtAmount.Value
```

You can just do this:

```
Range("C20").Offset(1, 0) = txtAmount.Value
```